# Add captions that respect figure numbering to "animated" images in columns in one slide

Tags: beamer, graphics, animations

I need to have captions under images, I'm using the columns environment so I can put images on top of eachother and create an "animation", but by doing that I had to get rid of figures and therefore I can't add captions to the images. Is there a way to keep this "animation" and have captions that follow the same numbering as my other figures?

```
%% DOCUMENT CLASS %%
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}

%% PACKAGES %%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

%% ADD FIGURE NUMBERING %%
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{horse}{:\quad} 
\captionsetup{
  labelsep = horse,
  figureposition = bottom
} 
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]

%% BEGIN DOCC %% 
\begin{document}

\frame{ 
  \begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{center}
      \includegraphics[width=0.5025\textwidth]{scr/1.png}
      \caption{Some caption}
    \end{center}
  \end{figure}
}

\subsection{First subsection}
\frame{ \frametitle{Title}
  \begin{columns}
    \column{0.3\textwidth}
      \begin{enumerate}
        \item 1
        \item 2
        \item 3
        \item 4
      \end{enumerate}

    \column{0.7\textwidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics<1>[width=0.3\textwidth]{scr/2.png}%
      %\caption{I would like a caption here}
  
      \includegraphics<2>[width=0.4\textwidth]{scr/3.png}%
      %\caption{And I would like a caption here as well}
  \end{columns}
}
\end{document}
```

This is the result of the sample code above:

[image: 1st slide]

[image: 2nd slide (1st part)]

[image: 2nd slide (2nd part)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `figure` environments with columns and animation. No need to remove them:

```
%% DOCUMENT CLASS %%
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}

%% PACKAGES %%
\usepackage{caption}

%% ADD FIGURE NUMBERING %%
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{horse}{:\quad} 
\captionsetup{
  labelsep = horse,
  figureposition = bottom
} 
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]

%% BEGIN DOCC %% 
\begin{document}

\begin{frame} 
  \begin{figure}
      \includegraphics[width=0.5025\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
      \caption{Some caption}
  \end{figure}
\end{frame}

\subsection{First subsection}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Title}
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{0.3\textwidth}
      \begin{enumerate}
        \item 1
        \item 2
        \item 3
        \item 4
      \end{enumerate}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.7\textwidth}
      \begin{figure}
      \includegraphics<1>[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-duck}%
      \only<1>{\caption{I would like a caption here}}
      \includegraphics<2>[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-duck}%
      \only<2>{\caption{And I would like a caption here as well}}
      \end{figure}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

However if you would prefer a solution without a `figure` environment, you could use the `\captionof{figure}{...}` from the caption package to add a caption to images which are not in `figure` environments.

```
%% DOCUMENT CLASS %%
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}

%% PACKAGES %%
\usepackage{caption}

%% ADD FIGURE NUMBERING %%
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{horse}{:\quad} 
\captionsetup{
  labelsep = horse,
  figureposition = bottom
} 
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]

%% BEGIN DOCC %% 
\begin{document}

\begin{frame} 
  \begin{figure}
      \includegraphics[width=0.5025\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
      \caption{Some caption}
  \end{figure}
\end{frame}

\subsection{First subsection}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Title}
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{0.3\textwidth}
      \begin{enumerate}
        \item 1
        \item 2
        \item 3
        \item 4
      \end{enumerate}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.7\textwidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics<1>[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-duck}%
      \only<1>{\captionof{figure}{I would like a caption here}}
      \includegraphics<2>[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-duck}%
      \only<2>{\captionof{figure}{And I would like a caption here as well}}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems to work seamlessly so far, thank you.

Comment: @mamimom892 You're welcome!